# Существуют ли какие нибудь браузер плагины автоподбора правильных селекторов для jQuery и phpQuery?

Tags: jquery, браузер, плагин, css-selectors, phpquery

Существует куча удобный плагинов для определения кода цвета (RGB, HEX) на html странице, когда просто тыкаешь нужный элемент на странице и тебе плагин сразу выдает его RGB или HEX цвет.

Есть ли какие нибудь плагины для браузеров (FireFox, Chrome) которые по аналогии при нажатие на элемент страницы показывают правильный селектор для его поиска средствами jQuery или phpQuery? Который можно было бы потом обычным копипастом вставить в $('selector')?

Например мне нужно по быстрому узнать селектор ссылок в блоке правой колонки какого нибудь сайта. Тыкаю в него мышкой мне сразу выдает к примеру 'div.rightBar div.menu a'

Comment: Думаю, тут есть сомнения в целесообразности такого подхода. В большинстве случаев искать элемент во всем DOM - не нужно. Допустим, вы уже определили какой-нибудь контейнер `var container = $('.container')`; И если вам надо найти что-нибудь внутри него, то выгодней искать так `var elem = container.find('elemSelector')`, тогда jquery проходит не по всему dom, а только внутри container, а это выгодней в плане вычислений. Соответственно, такие селекторы зависят от логики вашего приложения и плагины вряд-ли смогут подсказать их в этом случае.

Answer (score 0):

например в Chrome:

1)Правой кнопкой мыши нажимаем на элемент

2)Исследовать элемент

3) Правой кнопкой на элемент в HTML  дереве

4) Copy -> Copy selector

Answer (score 0):

> правильный селектор

Это понятие очень относительно, т.к. зависит от нужд разработчика. Если нужно найти один элемент, и он всего один на странице, то достаточно обратиться к нему по его классу/айди а-ля `$('.className')`. Если таких несколько, то никто, кроме вас не знает, какой нужен результат: нужно выбрать только один из них (возможно, надо уточнить конкретный элемент через его уникального родителя `$('#parent .className')`, либо выбрать самый первый `$('#parent .className:first-child')`) из них) или все сразу.
Потому универсального подхода нет, выбор обращения к элементу зависит от проекта и от потребностей разработчика.

Чтобы узнать, какие классы/айди есть у элемента, достаточно встроенных средств разработчика в любом браузере (например, в Хроме/Файрфоксе он вызывается нажатием клавиши `F12`, а далее ищем по дереву элементов; либо нажимаем на элемент правой кнопкой мыши и выбираем "Просмотреть код" в Хроме/"Исследовать элемент" в Мозилле), а далее уже надо размышлять, как построить выборку, чтобы захватить все нужные элементы.

Comment: я так и делаю. Но порой это довольно муторно т.к. бывают сраницы где нет четкого id или class, а есть куча вложенных друг в друга дивов, списков или ячеек таблиц приходится ползать по всему коду страницы и смотреть самому как правильно составить селектор к примеру для phpQuery